# Getting an error when creating a simple Apps Script trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I have a new Forms response spreadsheet that I'm trying to trigger off.  I don't make changes (yet) to the default myFunction() method and try to add a trigger.  The first field tries to auto-populate forever, spinning and spinning, while I get this error message:

> You cannot create a trigger without a target function, please add functions to the attached script.

I've done some online searching, and there are very few similar issues out there, and zero solutions for me.

Answer (score 0):

`ScriptApp.newTrigger("must have a function name here not a function declaration")`

```
function imanoob(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  e.source.toast('I am a noob');
}
```

Copy both functions into script editor and save them.
Run the second one first and then edit any cell on any tab or sheet.

```
function createImANoobTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'imanoob').length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('imanoob').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, this noob (me) didn't know you could do that programmatically.  Thanks!

Comment: If the entry point is going to be myFunction(), where do I put this code so it's called first and sets the trigger to myFunction()?  No static methods allowed I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating a trigger either manually or programmatically you should save the Google Apps Script project.

Tip: Replace the default project name by something descriptive otherwise you might eventually end with a lot of "Untitled project".

One advantage of doing this programmatically from the script editor is that when clicking on the Run button if the script was not save at least one time it will prompt for the project name and save the project.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#your_first_script

Comment: Thanks so much!  Yeah, I know to change "myFunction" to something useful, but I was just trying to solve my trigger problem in the Dashboard, which is broken.  I see the option in the Editor to change the main function (entry point) in a dropdown, so I pointed that to an init function that has my trigger setup in that.  Nice!

Comment: @rostaman The tip is not about changing the default function name is about changing the default **project** name :)

Comment: By the other hand, the function selector in the editor toolbar only have effects when running / debugging the code directly from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var formData = e.values;
  var name = formData[1];   // Assuming 'Full Name' is the second          column (index 1)
  var email = formData[2];  // Assuming 'Email' is the third column     (index 2)
  var message = formData[3]; // Assuming 'Comments' is the fourth column (index 3)

  var subject = 'New Contact Us Form Submission';
  var body = 'Name: ' + name + '\nEmail: ' + email + '\nMessage: ' +   message;

  MailApp.sendEmail('mc_shell@hotmail.com', subject, body);
}
```

I created a script in Apps Script to send an email when someone fills in an embedded Google Contact Us form. When I try to create a trigger for the script I get a dialog box asking me to log on to the same account I'm in for an unknown project event though I have saved and named the project